# How to fix 'terminated' while using rs.getString

Tags: java, sql

When trying to pull from an SQL database, I get  in Java console.

I am able to enter my ID manually in the prepareStatement, but I can't use setString to work with with the prepareStatement.

I haven't throught of too much to try, but I did find that the issue is within the while statement.  rs.next returns false when it should return true.   The information in SQL has been committed, and I can call all of the information in java using a function that reads out the entire table.

```
getemployeeDataById("01");
```

```
private static void getemployeeDataById(String e_id) {
    DBConnection dbConnection = DBConnection.getInstance();
    PreparedStatement ps;

    try {
        ps = dbConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement("select * from employee where E_ID = ?");
        ps.setString(1, e_id);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("ename"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

SQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(E_ID CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
ENAME CHAR(25),
DOB CHAR(25),
EMAIL CHAR(25),
PHONE CHAR(25),
ADDRESS CHAR(25));

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
VALUES
('01','JEREMY MANN','12/23/1992','jeremy@jeremy.com','317-528-1234','123 CandyCane Lane');
```

I am expecting to get the name outputted in the console, so for this example it would be "JEREMY MANN."  The code runs and then in the Eclipse Java console it shows  Application [Java Application].  It runs into an issue within the while statement, but I'm not sure what's causing rs.next to be false.

Comment: Are you committing after executing the insert statement?

Comment: What type of SQL db are you using? (oracle, mysql, etc)

Comment: @Jordan I am committing after the insert statement yes.

Comment: @jhell I am using oracle express 11g

Comment: @TheImpaler The value does seem to be exactly 01

Comment: Are any records returned when you run that sql query against the db in an oracle client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle 11g (well, Oracle versions generally) CHAR is a fixed width type, and if you give it a value shorter than the given width, it will be padded with blanks (which might not be obvious if you just dumped the table contents). In this case, your key is length 3, but the string "01" is length 2, so that won't work.

Try VARCHAR2 for the column types, that's a variable length string.

Comment: This fixed it, although I had to re-enter my data, because when you switch from CHAR to VARCHAR2 for your datatype, it still keeps those blanks in here.  Thanks for helping!